# Replace the keys of a dictionary by their associated value, within an input string identifying the occurrences of those keys in said input string

Tags: python, string, dictionary

```py
import re, datetime

input_text = "el 30 de octubre de 2021"   #example 1
input_text = "del dia 1 de diciembre del año 2020"   #example 2
input_text = "de este 12 del mes de septiembre de 2020"   #example 3
input_text = "de este 12 del mes de septiembre"   #example 4
input_text = "del dia 21 del mes de noviembre"   #example 5

es_month_dict = { "enero":"01", "febrero":"02", "marzo":"03", "abril":"04", "mayo":"05", "junio":"06", "julio":"07", "agosto":"08","septiembre":"09", "octubre":"10", "noviembre":"11", "diciembre":"12" }

#replacement order is important
input_text = input_text.replace(" dia ", " ")
input_text = input_text.replace(" del mes ", " ")
input_text = input_text.replace(" mes ", " ")
input_text = input_text.replace(" del año ", " ")
input_text = input_text.replace(" año ", " ")

#replacement, for example:  "enero" --> "01"

#only if the year is not indicated, the current year is placed
if():
    input_text = input_text + str(datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%Y'))

print(repr(input_text)) #output
```

the **correct output** you would need to obtain in each of the examples:

```
"el 30 de 10 de 2021"   #for example 1
"del 1 de 12 del 2020"   #for example 2
"de este 12 de 09 de 2020"   #for example 3
"de este 12 de 09 de 2022"   #for example 4
"del 21 de 11 de 2022"   #for example 5
```

How should I replace the dictionary `es_month_dict` keys by their value within the input string?
How should I concatenate the year if it is not indicated? Should I do it before replacing the elements of the dictionary `es_month_dict` or after it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- iterate over the pairs of you dict, key is the part to replace, value the part to replace with
- put all the words to delete in the same list, and iterate to remove them
- use a regex to check if the strings ends with 4 digits, or not

```
es_month_dict = {"enero": "01", "febrero": "02", "marzo": "03", "abril": "04", "mayo": "05", "junio": "06",
                 "julio": "07", "agosto": "08", "septiembre": "09", "octubre": "10", "noviembre": "11",
                 "diciembre": "12"}

deletion_words = ["dia", "del mes", "mes", "del año", "año"]

def transform(value):
    for deletion_word in deletion_words:
        value = value.replace(f" {deletion_word} ", " ")

    for month_name, month_nb in es_month_dict.items():
        value = value.replace(month_name, month_nb)

    if not re.search(r".*\d{4}$", value):
        value += " de " + datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%Y')

    return value
```

---

```
input_text = "el 30 de octubre de 2021"
print(transform(input_text))
input_text = "del dia 1 de diciembre del año 2020"
print(transform(input_text))
input_text = "de este 12 del mes de septiembre de 2020"
print(transform(input_text))
input_text = "de este 12 del mes de septiembre"
print(transform(input_text))
input_text = "del dia 21 del mes de noviembre"
print(transform(input_text))
```

```
el 30 de 10 de 2021
del 1 de 12 2020
de este 12 de 09 de 2020
de este 12 de 09 de 2022
del 21 de 11 de 2022
```